# If I create a git repo on github, does it automatically become a npm package?

Tags: github, npm

**Question1**:
If I create a git repo on github, does it automatically become a npm package?

**Question2**:
If I publish a public NPM package, does it automatically shows up on github?

Comment: Short answer, no....

Comment: No to both. There is no connection at all between the two, except that almost all code in NPM is also posted to GitHub.

Comment: Expanding on @JimStewart's comment, you can install from github using npm, but it still isn't an npm package in the normal sense.